# cx_Freeze Python

Tags: python

Здравствуйте разработчики.

Как-то здесь мелькала тема, в которой упоминалась библиотека cx_Freeze для создания бинарников из Python. Большое спасибо тому человеку.

Тем не менее есть вопросы:

1. Можно ли с ее помощью создать бинарник для 32х битной ОС, имея Python32 для 64bit и, соответственно, cx_Freeze тоже для 64bit?
2. Если создать бинарник для 32х битной ОС, каковы шансы, что он будет работать на 64х?
3. Можно ли с помощью данной утилиты затолкать полностью все в *.exe? Не оставляя отдельно архивов с исходниками?

BTW: OS Windows 7

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можно ли с ее помощью создать бинарник для 32х битной ОС, имея Python32 для 64bit и, соответственно, cx_Freeze тоже для 64bit?

Нет, потому что cx_Freeze берет библиотеки из того Питона, который установлен (под которым запущен сам cx_Freeze). Но по идее можно установить два Python 32- и 64-bit, и запускать скрипт под ними по отдельности.

> Если создать бинарник для 32х битной ОС, каковы шансы, что он будет работать на 64х?

Вероятность близка к 100%

> Можно ли с помощью данной утилиты затолкать полностью все в *.exe? Не оставляя отдельно архивов с исходниками?

На данный момент - нет ([ссылка на FAQ](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables)), но такое умеет делать py2exe.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно не совсем в тему, но...
Задавался я ранее теми же вопросами что и Вы. Раньше использовал py2exe потом сверху проходился RARом для запаковки в один бинарник. Работало, но кривовато - требовало различные dllки от студии.
Читал тут про cx_Freeze, пробовал - не понравилось, уже не помню почему, возможно руки не для скуки...
Меня спас pyinstaller, радости моей не было предела, потому что все сразу заработало.
Установка:

```
python setup.py install
python Configure.py
```

Создание спецификации

```
python Makespec.py --onefile D:\moden\proj_name\src\proj_name.py
```

Пример билдящего батника:

```
set home=%cd%
cd /d "c:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-1.5.1\"
python Build.py proj_name\proj_name.spec
copy swapy-ob\dist\proj_name.exe %home%\proj_name.exe
cd /d %home%
```

1. Пробовал собирать под Python 32 на x32 - работало нормально до 32, 64.
2. 100%
3. Уверенное ДА!

В пользу pyinstaller скажу, что **неожиданно**, заработал проект, который и не предполагалось так использовать, на Windows 2000.

Comment: @moden, спасибо, и работает на Питоне 3.2?

Comment: К сожалению не пробовал.

Comment: А жаль:) Это я и подразумевал под Python32

Comment: Как говорит их документация:

PyInstaller 1.5.1  -> for Python 2.2 - 2.7

Поэтому, не подходит, к сожалению, но на заметку возьму